# Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libqt5ftp5-dev"

Tags: 18.04, debian, aptitude, qt5

I use following command to install packages on UBUNTU1804.

```
sudo aptitude -R -y --allow-untrusted install libqt5ftp5-dev

Error: Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libqt5ftp5-dev"
```

So, how can I install packages like `libqt5ftp5-dev`, `xar`?

Comment: Why do you need that pakcage?

Comment: we first install a list of package on a UBUNTU18.04 (Azure agent pool) and build a C++ project.

Comment: Please, show us a guide you follow. Maybe that guide is deprecated and some steps are not compatible with 18.04.

Comment: @liangming2003 please make your question more reproducible. For now it is a quest for us, we may not have time to dig the whole internet to find your guide and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [article](http://lbxyz.club/2019/06/16/Qt%E7%BC%96%E8%AF%91QFtp/) that could be helpful. Written for windows, but maybe you could use it some way:

**Qt compilation QFtp**
Qt has reached version 5.x, and the `QFtp` class is no longer the object of default installation. In the new version of Qt, the `QNetworkAccessManager` class is used instead of `QFtp`. However, only basic methods such as get and push are retained, and `QFtp` is required to adopt other commands.Encountered several pits during the compilation process, record it. (Mingw + QtCreator)

First use the command to clone qftp in the qt official code repository ( https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtftp.git/ ). After downloading, open the pro file and find the ./src/qftp/qftp.pro file. will

```
CONFIG + = static
 CONFIG-= shared
change to

CONFIG + = static
 CONFIG + = shared
```

After this, you can generate static library (* .a) and dynamic link library (* .dll) files. But at this time I compiled the project and reported an error:

```
perl is not an internal or external command, nor a runnable program
or batch file
```

followed by a lot of things. This error appears when compiling a pl file, and I happen to be missing perl. So go to the official website to download (requires account registration, please note that the "create environment variable in path" option must be checked during the installation process), restart the computer after installation, and then compile.

If you are prompted that you cannot find a header file called "QFtp / qurlinfo.h", you need to reference the third header file in `./src/qftp/Headers/qftp.h`

```
# include  <QFtp / qurlinfo.h>
```

Change to

```
# include  <qurlinfo.h>
```

In this way, after compilation, there will be `libQt5Ftp.a, libQt5Ftpd.a, Qt5Ftp.dll, Qt5Ftp.prl, Qt5Ftpd.dll, Qt5Ftpd.prl in ./build-qtftp-Qt5_12.../lib. Then enter/ lib folder, paste libQt5Ftp.a, libQt5Ftpd.a, Qt5Ftp.prl, Qt5Ftpd.prl into it, and then go toPaste Qt5Ftpd.dll, Qt5Ftp.dll` in `/bin`, and then goPaste the modified `qftp.h` and `qurlinfo.h` in `/include/QtNetwork` and create a file named `QFtp` (no suffix), open the file with Notepad and write a line

```
# include  "qftp.h"
```

save document.

Let's go back to the configuration file that needs to use QFtp project to add

```
LIBS + = 
-lQt5Ftpd \ 
-lQtNetwork \
```

Then you can `#include <QtNetwork/QFtp>` in the project's header file

Note that because the `Qt5Ftp` library requires `QtNetwork` objects, ftp should be on it. Otherwise, an error similar to error: `undefined reference to QFtp :: QFtp (QObject *)` will appear during compilation.